# Get Deezer Waveform via API or URL

Tags: http, web-applications, deezer

I recently saw this Deezer Waveform in my Deezer-Explore-Feed:
http://cdn-images.deezer.com/images/waveform/9e5387f693247f77cd4a5bfa722d2ab3-0.png

It is similar to those used by soundcloud and seems to be avaiable to publicity via the above URL.

The linked Waveform is from the Track with the ID 86543213, called LA.Love by Fergie.

The only problem is that i dont know how to get the deezer-waveform-url for another ID, if it is possible to convert the ID somehow or if we need to use a specific API function.

I would really appreciate it if anyone has an idea on how to retrieve the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Icon near the Heart shape. It's call Share. Copy URL paste to Clip board then Open Deezer downloader, paste the URL address. Then CONVERT, Download

Comment: Hello user, could you please explain which downloader your mean? Maybe i can look at it's source code, if it is able to retreive the wave form

Answer (score 0):

> The linked Waveform is from the Track with the ID 86543213, called LA.Love by Fergie.

The ID doesn't exist when making a call to  `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{track_id}.json?client_id={your_api_key}`.

If the track your looking for has been modified and you still have the ID, you can just use the link template above and find the data you're looking for under the `waveform-url` attribute.

Comment: Hey francis, thank you for your response. Unfortunately you are posting an url to the soundcloud API while i need one for the Deezer API.